# CakePHP3 PUT with associated entity

Tags: associations, entity, cakephp-3.0, put

Today I stumbled across a problem, which I never really thought about before. I'm using the friendsofcake/CRUD plugin and try to update an entity with a belongsTo() relation, like this:

```
class UsersTable extends Table {

     public function initilialize(array $config) 
     {
           $this->belongsTo('Organisations')
     ...
```

A angular client calls `GET /users/1` to retrieve the following data:

```
$data = [
    'id' = 1,
    'username' => 'kylekatarn',
    'organistion_id' => 1,
    'organisation' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'label' => 'The Empire'
    ]
 ];
```

The client also has a list of all available organisations from `GET /organistaions`:

```
$organisations = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'label' => 'The Empire'
    ],[
        'id' => 2,
        'label' => 'Rebel Alliance'
    ]
]
```

Now Kyle Katarn defects to the Rebel Alliance and the angular client of Rebel fleet commands user database sends me data like this to `PUT /users/1`:

```
$data = [
    'id' => 1,
    'username' => 'kylekatarn',
    'organisation_id' => 1,
    'organisation' => [
        'id' => 2,
        'label' => 'Rebel Alliance'
    ]
];
```

My intention is that User kylekatarn should switch from `organisation_id = 1` to the new organisation found in organisation object. For some reason I thought that this should work out of the box, but instead the ORM adds a new entry for organisation.

After some digging around I found that the Organisation entity, didn't had set 'id' to be accessible. After I added 'id' to the list of accessible entity members, everything worked fine.

Now my question would be, if this is a good way to handle such problems? Are there any pitfalls on setting id to accessible? Or would it be better to update the associated entity with `user.organisation_id` in my case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to associate the user to a different existing organisation, then you should change the respective foreign key field, ie `organisation_id`, and leave `organisation` unchanged, or better yet don't even submit it, as it would get marked as dirty (which means it should be saved) if it contains fields with non-scalar values, even if the submitted values are identical to the existing ones.

You should only modify `organisation` if you want to either update the currently associated origanisation record (for that purpose you must pass the current primary key, and it doesn't have to be set to be accessible for that purpose), or if you want to create a new organisation and associate it with the user.

If you wanted to associate the user to a different existing organisation, and update that organisation in the same saving operation, that's when you'd run into a problem, as that would require the primary key field to be accessible (mass assignable).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comprehensible answer ndm. I think in my case I would change back the accessible ids and make the client send organisation_id in case the organisation is changed and an object organisation if the user should get into a completly new organisation.